# SVG—get absolute transform to element

Tags: svg, affinetransform

I have the following svg:

```
<svg id="setup" width="428" height="428" viewBox="0 0 428 428">

    <!-- matrix A-->
    <g transform="matrix(5, 0, 0, 8, 10, 15)">
        <svg width="300" height="300">

            <!-- matrix B-->
            <g transform="matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2)">

                <!-- matrix C-->
                <rect transform="matrix(2, 0, 0, 2, 3, 3)" x="10" y="10" width="10" height="10" style="fill:#00ff00;stroke-width:0;" />
            </g>
        </svg>
    </g>
</svg>
```

There is a nested svg within the first, whereby the inner svg is transformed by the group it is contains. Within this one is another group, containing a `rect`, what also has some transformation applied.

I am looking for a way to get to absolute which should be the product of `ABC` (reference the comments above).

I tried these variations (r is a reference to the `<rect … />` above):

```
#1: r.getTransformToElement(r.farthestViewportElement);

result:

| 2 0 5 |
| 0 2 5 |
| 0 0 1 |

what is B times C

#2: r.getTransformToElement(r.nearestViewportElement);

result:

| 0.4  0.00 -1.00 |
| 0.0  0.25 -1.25 |
| 0.0  0.00  1.00 |

what is that?

#3: r.getScreenCTM();

result:

| 10  0 531.5 |
|  0 16 187.5 |
|  0  0   1.0 |

what actually seems to be the transformation of the svg on the overall page times ABC.
```

So what is the way to get `ABC`?

Thanks in ahead!

**EDIT**

I found a way to gain that matrix, but I hope that there is a better way to do it and I am curious for this!

so here is the code:

```
var svg = document.getElementById('setup'),
    ABC = svg.getScreenCTM().inverse().multiply(r.getScreenCTM());
```

**EDIT#2**

I must admit here that variant #1 works fine in Firefox, but not in Chromium.